# NTE2013 base inputs

Tags: arduino, transistors, resistors

I have an [NTE2013](http://datasheet.octopart.com/NTE2013-NTE-Electronics-datasheet-32652.pdf) which I want to use with an Arduino. I may be driving the base pins directly off of the Arduino or perhaps off of a [74HC595](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/SN74HC595.pdf). Should I use resistors between the outputs and the base inputs to the NTE2013 to limit current? If so, about what resistor value ranges would work best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NTE2013 has the base current-limiting resistors (2700Ω) built in. You can connect its inputs directly to the '595 outputs.

Comment: That's what I suspected from the documentation. I just wanted to make good darn and sure. Thanks!